# Keys from debug/release.config always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, configuration, key

In both the debug and release config files I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
  </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="GlobalValue1" value="hello" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

The key, however, is always read as null by the controller, I've published the site as debug and release and either way the variable is seen as null.

I reference the key using:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GlobalValue1"];
```

and return it to the front end using:

```
public string SendKey()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GlobalValue1"];
}
```

The result is always null.

When searching for solutions the answers are that the user is trying to view it while running locally, and it will work when published, but I publish and the values are still null.

Comment: Do you also have the enclosing `<configuration>` tag in the config file?

Comment: where is your config file located? check the output folder of your binary/dll to see if it is indeed there.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I've added full config xml to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the difference between the Web or App config files and its transformations. All sites has a base Web.config or App.Config which has the properties that you use during the development of the sites. These properties may or may not be used on the debug and release builds of the site respectively and this is when Web.Release.config and Web.Debug.config comes into play.

In these files you should put the way you are transforming your web.config or app.config by replacing or removing the values. You can read more in detail in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Lets say you defined in your (web/app).config the following:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="GlobalValue1" value="hello" />
</appSettings>
```

In your release or debug files you should put the following in order to change its value:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="GlobalValue1" value="hello world" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

This means that when it find the configuration appSettings/add[Key="GlobalValue1"] it will set the attributes defined in the transformation.

You can find more information in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx